# Azure function blobtrigger should not trigger on subfolders

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-trigger, kraken-image-optimizer

I have created a blobtrigger that runs whenever i upload to my container. 
But since i am going to use kraken to process the image, and then reupload the processed images in a subfolder of the original image.

I am unable to figure out how to make sure that i am not going to trigger on kraken uploading images to the container..

**Folder setup**

- Foldername

  - file.jpg
  - file.jpg

**Kraken uploads to the folder (krakenfolder)**

- foldername

  - file.jpg
  - file.jpg
  - krakenfolder

    - krakenprocessedimage.jpg
    - krakenprocessedimage.jpg

Currently my blobtrigger also triggers on subfolders.. 
how can check for it or stop it from doing this?

**My blobtrigger as it is currently**

```
[FunctionName("ProductBlobDispatch")]
        public static async void Run(
            [BlobTrigger("products/{name}")]
            Stream myBlob,
            string name,
            ILogger log,
            string blobTrigger,
            [Queue("scanpipe-media-dispatch")] IAsyncCollector<MediaDispatchModel> imageProcessor)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Blob trigger on product upload, processed blob\n Name: {name}\n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            //convert stream to model.

            var model = new ImageProcessingModel()
            {
                Url = "/"+name,
                IsProduct = true,
                IsDeleted = false,
            };

            await imageProcessor.AddAsync(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As blob storage does not have "physical" folders, there is no way. Everything in `name` is part of the blob in the same flat structure. Even if the name is `my/first/level/virtual/folder/text.txt`

So you have to filter it out in your code or use containers as your "folder".

To add: There are limited [filter capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#blob-name-patterns) but none of those do seem to apply to what you are looking for.

Comment: How can i filter it out ?

Comment: for example simply check if your blob `name` only has one `/`? That would mean the blob is your top level folder. If it has more slashes it would be in a virtual subfolder

Comment: @andrelange91 see my edit. There are limited filters but probably ot enough for you

Answer (score 0):

I do not know it if is the best way of doing it, but it works for me.

I check on '/' with

```
name.Count(x => x == '/') > 1
```